# print '{' using .format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing, string.format

I want to print the string: `[{X}]`, while X is an int. when I'm using `.format` I get into trouble with printing the char '{' because it's a part of the format.

I tried to use the code line:

```
print("[{{}}]".format(X))
```

and I get the error:

```
Single '}' encountered in format string.
```

Is there a way around this error?

Comment: I don't get any error with you show; I get `[{}]` as output. You still need the brace group that actually expands to the value of X, though: `print("[{{{}}}]".format(X))`.

Answer (score 1):

`{{}}` are used to print `{}`. If you want something like this `{something}`. Try this

```
X=10
print("[{{{}}}]".format(X))
# [{10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

While I can't reproduce the error you claim, you only produce the characters needed to display the braces, with no replacement field.

```
fmt = "["  # the opening bracket
fmt += "{{"  # the literal {
fmt += "{}"  # the replacement field
fmt += "}}"  # the literal }
fmt += "]"  # the closing bracket

assert fmt == "[{{{}}}]"
#         not "[{{}}]", as you have

assert fmt.format(3) == "[{3}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `format()` isn't an absolute necessity, then you can do something like that:

```
x = 12
print("[{%i}]" %x)
# [{12}]
```

Which is way cleaner and more understandable than:

```
print("[{{{}}}]".format(X))
```